# SQL Server Concatenate GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that looks like this

```
SELECT J.JobID,T.Title FROM JobsTagMap J
Left Join Tags T
ON J.TagID=T.TagID
```

That returns the following dataset (simplified, JobID is actually a UniqueIdentifier)

```
JobID    Title
1        Tag1
1        Tag2
2        Tag2
2        Tag5
2        Tag9
```

Now, i'd like to group this by the JobID-column and concatenate the Title, so the results is as following

```
JobID    Title
1        Tag1,Tag2
2        Tag2,Tag5,Tag9
```

How would i do that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server

Comment: I had one of the answers but the reference above is excellent.  The answer from Arion uses the same approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using sql server 2005+. Then you can do like this:

```
SELECT 
    JobsTagMap.JobID,
    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT 
                ',' +Title
            FROM
                Tags
            WHERE
                Tags.TagID=JobsTagMap.TagID
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
    ,1,1,'') AS Title
FROM JobsTagMap
```

**EDIT**

Because you did not show us the table structure and the data in the different tables. It was a lite bit hard to know. So I assume that your table structure looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE JobsTagMap
(
    JobID INT,
    TagID INT
)

CREATE TABLE Tags
(
    TagID INT,
    Title VARCHAR(100)
)
```

With this data:

```
INSERT INTO JobsTagMap
VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,4),(2,5)

INSERT INTO Tags
VALUES(1,'Tag1'),(2,'Tag2'),(3,'Tag2'),(4,'Tag5'),(5,'Tag9')
```

If you are getting that data that you are showing the `JobID` cannot be unique. You might have the a `Job` table somewhere where it is unique. If you just want to use these table that you are showing then you need to do something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JobID ORDER BY JobID) AS RowNbr,
        JobsTagMap.*
    FROM
        JobsTagMap
)
SELECT
    *,
    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT 
                ',' +Title
            FROM
                Tags
                JOIN JobsTagMap
                    ON Tags.TagID=JobsTagMap.TagID
            WHERE
                JobsTagMap.JobID=CTE.JobID
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
    ,1,1,'') AS Title
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr=1
```

This will get you this result:

```
1   1   1   Tag1,Tag2
1   2   2   Tag2,Tag5,Tag9
```

So in the future always show what **table structure** and it **data**. That will give you better answers

Comment: I tried a little with this, and added a Group by at last, "GROUP BY JobsTagMap.JobID", but then i get this error

"Column 'JobsTagMap.TagID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 1):

I use a scalar function for exactly that.   There are going to be some purist that decry should never use a row based operation but hey this works and if you are only returning a few rows then response time is fine.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[JoinMVText]

(

  @sID int,

  @fieldID tinyint

)

RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)

AS 

BEGIN

   DECLARE @MVtextList varchar(max)

   SELECT @MVtextList = COALESCE(@MVtextList + '; ', '') + docMVtext.value

   FROM docMVtext with (nolock) 

   WHERE docMVtext.sID = @sID and fieldID = @fieldID

   RETURN @MVtextList

END
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as you did and I figured out how to workaround slow sub-selects.

Using **GROUP BY**:

```
(70500 rows affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 94 ms,  elapsed time = 833 ms.
```

Using **Sub-Selects**:

```
(70500 rows affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1469 ms,  elapsed time = 2323 ms.
```

**Sub-selects are more then 4 times slower...**

Here's the solution:

```
SELECT 
    J.JobID,
    STRING_AGG(ISNULL(T.Title, ''), ',') as Title
FROM JobsTagMap J
LEFT JOIN Tags T ON J.TagID = T.TagID
GROUP BY J.JobID;
```

*Let me know if something is not clear enough :)*

Comment: What is STRING_AGG? it is not built in function.