# MySQL select all from 3 tables different amount of rows

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I want to retrieve a list of all members and all members boats.
The way I'm doing it I get the members info for each boat a member has. So if a member John Smith has 3 boats, John Smith is displayed 3 times.
I want the name and info to be displayed once, and empty columns instead of duplicated along with the boats.

```
SELECT m.memberId, m.fName, m.lName, m.ssn, b.boatId, b.length, bt.type
FROM member AS m
RIGHT JOIN boat AS b
ON m.memberId = b.memberId
INNER JOIN boatType AS bt
ON b.boatTypeId = bt.boatTypeId
```

Comment: How would you determine which boat to be displayed for John Smith?

Comment: That's a display requirement that should be handled in your UI layer, not in your database result set.

Comment: Okey, but it's possible with sql?

Comment: Did you try using the distinct keyword? Or Group by might work

Comment: @user1121487: No, this is not possible with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joe suggested, you can use the GROUP_CONCAT and CONCAT functions in MySQL, like so.

```
   SELECT m.memberId, m.fName, m.lName, m.ssn, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(b.boatId, '(', bt.type, ':',b.length,' ft.)')
                       ORDER BY bt.boatId SEPARATOR '; ')
     FROM member AS m
LEFT JOIN boat AS b ON m.memberId = b.memberId
     JOIN boatType AS bt ON b.boatTypeId = bt.boatTypeId
 GROUP BY m.memberId, m.fName, m.lName, m.ssn
```

This will give you rows like this.

```
1 Larry Ellison 123-45-6789 USA 17(Americas Cup:113 ft.); Rising Sun(Diesel:453 ft.)
2 Ollie Jones 987-65-4321 Scruffy Guppy(Sunfish:12 ft.)
```

Comment: oops. That's what I get for not testing stuff. fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in Mysql to generate this type of query if I understand what your asking for:

```
 Owner 1 details, boat 1 details
                  boat 2 details
                  boat 3 details
 Owner 2 details, boat 4 details
                  boat 5 details
```

As note in a comment, this type of grouping is done in the display side, after you get back the data.

Comment: Yes thats what I wanted. Ok.. I thought it might. I think I did it in MS SQL.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a group by clause.

`GROUP BY m.member id, m.fName, m.lName, m.ssn`

As for the boatId, length and type fields, you'll have to decide which of the 3 boats' ID length and type (using your example) should be shown.

Comment: But the OP needs *all* of the boats returned in his result set.

Comment: All of the boats in ONE column?
Something like:
1 John Smith boat1,boat2,boat3

That's a little harder to do, but this might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461874/sql-server-concatenate-group-by

Comment: No. If that's what he wanted, he might be able to leverage [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) since he's using MySQL.