# SQL Server 2016 for JSON output integer array

Tags: arrays, sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

I'd like to get JSON with an array of integers using SQL Server 2016's `For JSON` feature. I'm stumped on array of integers.

Database table structures:

```sql
declare @Employees table (ID int, Name nvarchar(50))
insert into @Employees values
(1, 'Bob'),
(2, 'Randy')

declare @Permissions table (ID int, PermissionName nvarchar(50))
insert into @Permissions values
(1, 'Post'),
(2, 'Comment'),
(3, 'Edit'),
(4, 'Delete')

declare @EmployeePermissions table (EmployeeID int, PermissionID int)
insert into @EmployeePermissions values
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(2, 3)
```

Desired results:

```json
{"EmployeePermissions": [
  {"Employee":"Bob", "Permissions":[1,2]},
  {"Employee":"Randy", "Permissions":[1,2,3]}
]}
```

This is the closest I've gotten, but not quite what I want.

```sql
select
    e.Name as Employee,
    (select 
         convert(nvarchar(10),ep.PermissionID) as PermID 
     from @EmployeePermissions ep 
     where ep.EmployeeID=e.ID 
     for json path) as 'Permissions'
from
    @Employees e
for json path, root('EmployeePermissions')
```

returns:

```json
{"EmployeePermissions": [
  {"Employee":"Bob", "Permissions":[{"permID":1},{"permID":2}]},
  {"Employee":"Randy", "Permissions":[{"permID":1},{"permID":2},{"permID":3}]}
]}
```

**SOLUTION - SQL Server 2017 and on**

```sql
select
    e.Name as Employee,
    (select 
         '[' + STRING_AGG(ep.PermissionID, ',') + ']' 
     from @EmployeePermissions ep 
     where ep.EmployeeID=e.ID) as Permissions 
from
    @Employees e
for json path, root('EmployeePermissions')
```

Comment: Can you please share the working code, it will helps to give more answers

Comment: creat a view /resultset  using   for permID and then get result done  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461874/sql-server-concatenate-group-by

Comment: @Arulkumar - added my closest code.

Comment: If you can live with the problematic output from `SQL Server` I suggest you let the consumer know about these aliases. If you're using `Json.NET`, then see this excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48245381/419761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work on **SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later**

```
SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG(ep.PermissionID, ',') + ']'
FROM @EmployeePermissions ep
```

You have to cast your value to NVarchar(max) only if your result string exceed 8000bytes

```
SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG(cast(ep.PermissionID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ',') + ']'
FROM @EmployeePermissions ep
```

FullQuery

```
SELECT e.Name as Employee,
    (SELECT 
         '[' + STRING_AGG(cast(ep.PermissionID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ',') + ']' 
     FROM @EmployeePermissions ep 
     WHERE ep.EmployeeID=e.ID) as Permissions 
FROM
    @Employees e
FOR JSON PATH, root('EmployeePermissions')
```

Comment: yay. This does it with the STRING_AGG function that came into being in SQL Server 2017.  Thanks - I will be using this.

Comment: I couldn't edit your answer to include the full query, so I'll add at the end of my question.

Comment: I edited the answer with the full query.
After 6 years you can maybe get this topic checked ✓.     
regards ;)

Answer (score 11):

In AdventureWorks 2016 CTP3 JSON sample you can find a function that can clean array of key:value pairs and create array od values:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.ufnToRawJsonArray
GO
CREATE FUNCTION
[dbo].[ufnToRawJsonArray](@json nvarchar(max), @key nvarchar(400)) returns nvarchar(max)
AS BEGIN
       declare @new nvarchar(max) = replace(@json, CONCAT('},{"', @key,'":'),',')
       return '[' + substring(@new, 1 + (LEN(@key)+5), LEN(@new) -2 - (LEN(@key)+5)) + ']'
END
```

Just provide result of your SELECT FOR JSON expression as @json parameter and name of the key that you want to remove as second parameter. Probably something like:

```
select
e.Name as Employee,
JSON_QUERY(dbo.ufnToRawJsonArray(
    (select 
     convert(nvarchar(10),ep.PermissionID) as PermID 
     from @EmployeePermissions ep 
     where ep.EmployeeID=e.ID 
     for json path)
  , 'PermID'))
   as 'Permissions'
from
@Employees e
for json path, root('EmployeePermissions')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` to make `PermissionID` one string comma separated for each `Employee`, use `QUOTENANE` on it, then put all in variable and replace `"[` with `[` and `]"` with `]` :

```sql
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @json = REPLACE(REPLACE((
    SELECT  e.Name as [Employee],
            QUOTENAME(STUFF((SELECT ','+CAST(ep.PermissionID as nvarchar(10))
            FROM EmployeePermissions ep
            WHERE e.ID = ep.EmployeeID
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''))
            as [Permissions]
    FROM Employees e 
    FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('EmployeePermissions')
),'"[','['),']"',']')

SELECT @json
```

Output:

```json
{"EmployeePermissions":[
    {"Employee":"Bob","Permissions":[1,2]},
    {"Employee":"Randy","Permissions":[1,2,3]}
]}
```

**EDIT:**

Another way:

```sql
SELECT '{"EmployeePermissions":[' + STUFF((
SELECT  ',{"Employee":"' + e.Name + '","Permissions":[' +
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(PermissionID as nvarchar(10))
        FROM EmployeePermissions ep
        WHERE ep.EmployeeID = e.ID
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') +']}'
FROM Employees e
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') + ']}'
```

Output:

```json
{"EmployeePermissions":[
    {"Employee":"Bob","Permissions":[1,2]},
    {"Employee":"Randy","Permissions":[1,2,3]}
]}
```

Comment: Close, though I'm wanting an array of numbers, like this:  "Permissions":[1,2,3]

Comment: This is the right output, but I am not wanting strictly string concatenation techniques. The array part can use string tricks, but the outer query (which is simplified in this case) must use the "For JSON" feature.

Comment: Well, maybe in next version of SQL Server they add feature were you can call FOR JSON PATH without naming column or create arrays of values else way (like JSON_MODIFY append). But for now it come as it is. Hope you find answer for your question. :)

Comment: Thanks gofr1. I'm finding it hard to accept, after waiting so long for Microsoft to support JSON, that I have already reached limitations.

Comment: @JensFrandsen Yeah, I'm pretty disappointed I can't seem to figure out how to create a simple array of arrays with my data. I don't want any keys.

Comment: Any news on this? For the time being I'm just removing the keys right after parsing the JSON output in the application