# How to create JSON Array Inside JSON object using FOR JSON SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssms-2016, sql-server-json

How to create JSON Array Inside JSON object using FOR JSON SQL Server 2016 (TABLE to JSON)
Here is my query:

```
SELECT   
m.MeetingId AS tblMeeting_MeetingId,  
m.Attended AS tblMeeting_Attended, 
m3.CompanyId AS tblMeetingAttendants_CompanyId, 
m3.MeetingAttendantsId AS tblMeetingAttendants_AttendantNameWithTitle, 
m4.UserId AS tblMeetingAttendees_UserId, 
m5.BrokerId AS tblMeetingBroker_BrokerId 
FROM Bv.tblMeeting m 
LEFT JOIN Bv.tblMeetingAttendants m3 ON m.MeetingId = m3.MeetingId  
LEFT JOIN Bv.tblMeetingAttendees m4 ON m.MeetingId = m4.MeetingId  
LEFT JOIN Bv.tblMeetingBroker m5 ON m.MeetingId = m5.MeetingId  
WHERE m.MeetingId = 739 
FOR JSON AUTO, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

[image]

Above query gives me result like this:

```
[
{
    "tblMeeting_MeetingId": 739,
    "tblMeeting_Attended": false,
    "tblMeeting_MeetingSubject": " Benchmark China Internet Analyst",
    "m3": [
        {
            "tblMeetingAttendants_CompanyId": 83,
            "tblMeetingAttendants_AttendantNameWithTitle": 499,
            "m4": [
                {
                    "tblMeetingAttendees_UserId": null,
                    "m5": [
                        {
                            "tblMeetingBroker_BrokerId": 275
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tblMeetingAttendants_CompanyId": 83,
            "tblMeetingAttendants_AttendantNameWithTitle": 500,
            "m4": [
                {
                    "tblMeetingAttendees_UserId": null,
                    "m5": [
                        {
                            "tblMeetingBroker_BrokerId": 275
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tblMeetingAttendants_CompanyId": 83,
            "tblMeetingAttendants_AttendantNameWithTitle": 501,
            "m4": [
                {
                    "tblMeetingAttendees_UserId": null,
                    "m5": [
                        {
                            "tblMeetingBroker_BrokerId": 275
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

But i want result like this

```
[
{
    "tblMeeting_MeetingId": 739,
    "tblMeeting_Attended": false,
    "tblMeeting_MeetingSubject": " Benchmark China Internet Analyst",
    "tblMeetingAttendants_AttendantNameWithTitle": [499,500,501],
    "tblMeetingAttendees_UserId": null,
    "tblMeetingBroker_BrokerId": 275
}
]
```

Please reply as soon as possible
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is impossible without using string concatenation and writing your own functions. There is no magic JSON_ARRAY_AGGREGATE() function. I have been looking for one myself.
Here is a related question: [SQL Server 2016 for JSON output integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494211/sql-server-2016-for-json-output-integer-array)

Answer (score 0):

Can use JSON_QUERY with JSON PATH to format your data into a JSON array. I sampled just your MeetingID and MeetingAttendantID columns to demonstrate the concept

### Build JSON Array using JSON_QUERY

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #MeetingAttendance

CREATE TABLE #MeetingAttendance (MeetingID INT,AttendantID INT)
INSERT INTO #MeetingAttendance
VALUES (739,499)
,(739,500)
,(739,501)

SELECT tblMeeting_MeetingId = MeetingID
    ,tblMeetingAttendants_AttendantNameWithTitle = JSON_QUERY('['+STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"',AttendantID,'"'),',') + ']')   
FROM #MeetingAttendance
GROUP BY MeetingID
FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

### Results

```
{
    "tblMeeting_MeetingId": 739,
    "tblMeetingAttendants_AttendantNameWithTitle": [
        "499",
        "500",
        "501"
    ]
}
```