# Name array elements in Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json.net

Using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) 10.0.3. Consider the following sample:

```
class Foo
{
   [JsonProperty("ids")]
   public int[] MyIds { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously, the elements of the array are unnamed. Now consider the following `json`:

```
{
  "ids": [{
      "id": 1
    }, {
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

And then we try to parse it:

```
var json = @"{""ids"":[{""id"":1},{""id"":2}]}";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(son);
```

Parsing the above fails with the following message:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered
>   while parsing value: {. Path 'ids', line 1, position 9.

I know I can wrap `int` in a class and name it "id" there, but I'm wondering if this can be done without this extra work. The reason being what appears to be a limitation in `SQL Server 2016`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494211/sql-server-2016-for-json-output-integer-array).

Comment: Obvious thing to do would be to use a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

Comment: But with a custome converter your C# wouldn't match your JS. I suppose it depends on where you want to lie.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Not sure if `""` is that much better than `\"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a custom `JsonConverter` to translate between the two array formats:

```
class CustomArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public CustomArrayConverter(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray array = new JArray(JArray.Load(reader).Select(jo => jo[PropertyName]));
        return array.ToObject(objectType, serializer);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> items = (IEnumerable<T>)value;
        JArray array = new JArray(
            items.Select(i => new JObject(
                new JProperty(PropertyName, JToken.FromObject(i, serializer)))
            )
        );
        array.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // CanConvert is not called when the [JsonConverter] attribute is used
        return false;
    }
}
```

To use the converter, mark your array property with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute as shown below.  Note the type parameter for the converter must match the item type of the array, and the second parameter of the attribute must be the property name to use for the values in the JSON array.

```
class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("ids")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomArrayConverter<int>), "id")]
    public int[] MyIds { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a round-trip demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vUQKV1

Comment: this is briliant @Brian.

Comment: Hi I have a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59369351. If you are monitoring Brian could you take a look please?