# How to write the SQL query below mention table structure and JSON output using FOR JSON

Tags: sql, json

**How to write  the SQL query  below mention table structure and JSON output using FOR JSON.**

table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TreeView](
[AuditId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[FatherId] [int] NULL,
[MotherId] [int] NULL,
[EnglishName] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Description] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Image] [varchar](500) NULL,
```

JSON output

```
 { id: 1, title: "Meera Mohaideen", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/m.png" },
            { id: 2, title: "Rahman Beevi", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/f.png" },
            { id: 3, title: "Abdul Jabbar", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/m.png" },
            { id: 4, title: "Jahabar Natchiyal", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/f.png" },
            { id: 5, parents: [1,2] ,title: "AJhir Ali", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/m.png" },
          { id: 6, parents: [3, 4], title: "Kamila Begam", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/f.png" },
           { id: 7, parents: [5, 6], title: "Simra", description: "7", image: "demo/images/photos/f.png" }
```

Query

```
SELECT Id AS Id, 
CASE WHEN ISNULL(FatherId,0) <> 0 OR ISNULL(MotherId,0) <> 0 THEN 
CAST(FatherId AS VARCHAR(25)) + ',' + CAST(MotherId AS VARCHAR(25)) END AS parents, 
EnglishName AS title, 
[Description] AS Description, 
[Image] AS Image FROM TreeView 
FOR JSON AUTO
```

I tried  but result is {"Id":5,"parents":"1,2","title":"AJhir Ali"} 
but I am expecting this {"Id":5,"parents":[1,2],"title":"AJhir Ali"}

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT 
Id AS Id,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(FatherId,0) <> 0 OR ISNULL(MotherId,0) <> 0 THEN  CAST(FatherId AS VARCHAR(25)) + ',' + CAST(MotherId AS VARCHAR(25))   END AS parents,
EnglishName AS title,
[Description] AS Description,
[Image] AS Image
FROM TreeView FOR JSON AUTO

Comment: What is the problem with the query that you tried?

Comment: result is  {"Id":5,"parents":"1,2","title":"AJhir Ali"} but I am expecting this {"Id":5,"parents":[1,2],"title":"AJhir Ali"}

Comment: Can you edit your question to add these details?

Comment: I found the solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494211/sql-server-2016-for-json-output-integer-array)  Please answer my issue If some one know better solution.